# Checking if an image is a basis for $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So for our homework, we had the following problem:
[image: Problem]

I got the first one right by reasoning that since [1,1,1] was part of the vectors, any possible vector in $\mathbb R^3$ could be created.

However, using the same reasoning for the second is wrong apparently. Does [1,0,1] +[0,1,0] not create[1,1,1] (which should span $\mathbb R^3$)? Does it not? Did I fluke into part 1?

Comment: the span of $[1,1,1]$ is $[c,c,c]$, not all of $\mathbb R^3$; $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\2\end{bmatrix}$ is not in the span of $W_2$

Comment: You're right, how did I miss that.

Comment: 1. You can use determinant to check the linear independence and as $card(W_1)=\dim \mathbb{R}^3$, the result follows. 
2. The determinant of the matrix formed by the vectors of $W_2$ is equal to zero. What can you conclude?

Comment: to span $\mathbb R^3$, you need $3$ linearly independent vectors, but the zero vector (which is in $W_2$) is not linearly independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$W_1$ is a basis because $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=(x-y)\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+(y-z)\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} +z\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$,

but $W_2$ is not because $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ with $x\ne z$ is not in the span  of $W_2$.